# How to point a public domain on another server to your localhost on Linux?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

This is a rather hard question to ask as I am not sure what is is called. Basically I own a license for a product, which is licensed to one of my domains (eg. www.mysite.com). The problem is I need to test things locally before I make changes on my public website but I can't install it on my localhost because its Zend encrypted and only works on one domain name. I basically want my localhost server to believe that "www.mysite.com" is located on my localhost instead of trying to connect to it on the internet. Is this possible? I know it was with Windows, but I can't seem to find how to do this with Linux.

Thanks!

Comment: Theyh don't offer a development license you can install? That would be very strange.

Answer (score 6):

You could put a line in your `/etc/hosts` like this:

```
127.0.0.1 www.mysite.com
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Apache, you want to make a VirtualHost called "www.mysite.com" and then add "www.mysite.com" to `/etc/hosts` such as

```
127.0.0.1 localhost www.mysite.com
```

Then hit http://www.mysite.com in your browser and the virual host should handle the request locally. See [this Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, all you have to do is to edit `/etc/hosts`. You should add that line:

```
127.0.0.1 mysite.com www.mysite.com
```

Then `www.mysite.com` will be resolved to `127.0.0.1` which is your machine.

Answer (score 0):

not sure about linux but try updating your hosts file to add 127.0.0.1 to point to Your.Public.Domain.You.Want.ToSpoof

Answer (score 0):

You could temporarily override the domain name in your /etc/hosts file on your linux box. If you assign the domain for the www.mysite.com to be your localhost IP, it would reroute all traffic.